# Delete individual as friend suggestion

Tags: facebook

I don't want to completely turn off Facebook friend suggestions. But Facebook sometimes suggest people that I don't want to add as friends.

How can I stop Facebook ever again suggesting these individuals, but keep friend suggestion active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you should be able to rollover that suggestion, and a [X] should be visible to remove that suggestion. Other than that there is no other way.

Comment: The "x"  seems to only hide the suggestion. It reappears after some time.

Comment: That's your only option, the only thing extreme will be to block the user.

Comment: Block seems to work. I cannot see this person any more.